# Using facet_zoom to zoom into a time series graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use facet_zoom to 'zoom in' to particular year periods - 1985-86. 1997-98, 2010-11 and 2015-16 respectively. The code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=14))

sst <- read.csv("FINALSST.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
regions <- unique(sst$Region)
sst <- sst %>% mutate(Time=as.Date(Time, format="%d/%m/%Y"), 
                      Region=factor(Region, levels=regions))

sst2 <- sst %>% mutate(Time=floor_date(Time, unit="month")) %>%
  group_by(Time, Region, Variable) %>%
  summarise(Value=mean(Value, na.rm=TRUE), .groups="drop")

ggplot(sst2, aes(Time, Value, col=Variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Region, ncol=1) +
  theme(legend.position="top")

# Now add el nino years

en_s <- as.Date(c("01/01/1997", "01/01/2015"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
en_e <- as.Date(c("31/12/1998", "31/12/2016"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
ln_s <- as.Date(c("01/01/1985", "01/01/2010"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
ln_e <- as.Date(c("31/12/1986", "31/12/2011"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
elnino <- data.frame(start=en_s, end=en_e, Time=en_s, Value=Inf, event="El Nino")
lanina <- data.frame(start=ln_s, end=ln_e, Time=en_s, Value=Inf, event="Non-El Nino")

library(ggforce)

ggplot(sst2, aes(Time, Value, col=Variable)) +
  geom_rect(data=elnino, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=Inf, ymax=-Inf), 
            col=NA, fill="lightpink") +
  geom_rect(data=lanina, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, ymin=Inf, ymax=-Inf), 
            col=NA, fill="lightblue") +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Region, ncol=1) +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  labs(title = "Monthly average SSTs from 1985 to 2017")
```

I added facet_zoom to the final line but it produces the error 'subscript out of bounds'. The first 'zoom in' I am trying to achieve is 01/01/1997 to 31/12/1998. I have tried various methods but it still produces errors. Any suggestions for using facet_zoom on a time series graph?

Thanks!

Comment: OP, we're missing some data to make your code reproducible as well as the code for the line containing `facet_zoom()` that gives the error.  The assumption here is that the code you posted works fine as is, and the error *only* shows up when you add the `facet_zoom()` line, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct! It only appears as I run the line with facet_zoom()

Comment: You have a `facet_wrap()` command already, and are then supplying `facet_zoom(...)` when you get the error?  It's very important here to see the actual `facet_zoom()` line in the code, then.  The "subscript out of bounds" error likely means you are specifying a zoom that is outside of your data range in the parent plot.